# Infinite sequence problem

Tags: calculus

How can i solve this problem ?

$$\frac{\pi}{4}\lt\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+1}\lt\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The lower bound can be written as an integral which approximates the sum, and an associated upper bound can be obtained.

---

See the graph below.  Your sum is equal to the total area beneath the orange "zig-zag". The lower bound is equal to the total pink area, and the upper bound is the pink area plus the area of the gray rectangles.

[image]

---

A more rigorous approach: if we estimate the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} dx$ using the left-sided and right-sided Riemann sums, then we end up with the inequality
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + 1} < \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}dx 
< \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + 1} \implies \\
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + 1} < \frac{\pi}4
< \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + 1}.
$$
The fact that these sums are lower and upper bounds is a consequence of the fact that the integrand $\frac 1{x^2 + 1}$ is decreasing. It follows that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + 1} - \frac{\pi}{4} < 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + 1} - \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + 1} = \frac 12.
$$
Rearranging $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + 1} - \pi/4 < 1/2$ yields
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + 1} < \frac{\pi}4 + \frac 12,
$$
as was desired.

Comment: how can i apply this ? i dont understand.

Comment: Find two functions whose integrals approximate the sum

Comment: Bro im student at university.This is midterm question.Professor sends we.We didnt see this in lesson.I know integral test for convergence or divergence.But i guess you said different thing.Can you explain little more ? Thanks...

Comment: @MuratYetkinAslan I'll add a picture

Comment: Thank Bro ......

Comment: @MuratYetkinAslan See my latest edit

Comment: @MuratYetkinAslan Let me know if there are any issues with the picture. Unfortunately, the orange is very faintly orange.

Comment: So i guess first i find pink are for lower bound and pink+gray area for upper bound.And then i guess find orange line. Is it true ? There isnt problem picture

Comment: Bro i understood lower bound but i didnt understan upper bound.Can you explain please?

Comment: @MuratYetkinAslan Note that the gray rectangles overlap with the pink area. When I say to add up the area of the gray rectangles, I mean that you should include the area that overlaps with the pink. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes bro I feel clearly.Pink area pi/4.Pi/4 lower bound.But how can calculate upper bound with integration?

Comment: @MuratYetkinAslan You don't need to use integration! If you slide all the boxes to the left until they touch the black line at $x = 1$, then they form a single bar.

Comment: yess.I guess understood.Therefore upper bound's area will be (1*0.5) + pi/4. Thank bro.It worked very well for me..

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution. Let $x\in[n,n+1]$ and then
$n\le x$ for $n\ge1$ and $n\ge x-1$ for $n\ge 2$, one has
$$ \frac{1}{x^2+1}\le\frac{1}{n^2+1}\le\frac{1}{(x-1)^2+1}. $$
So
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}\frac{1}{n^2+1}dx\ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx=\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx=\frac{\pi}{4}. $$
On the other hand, 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+1}=\frac12+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}\frac{1}{n^2+1}dx\le \frac12+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}\frac{1}{(x-1)^2+1}dx=\frac12+\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx=\frac12+\frac{\pi}{4}. $$
So
$$ \frac\pi4\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+1}\le \frac12+\frac{\pi}{4}. $$

Comment: The only rigorous answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this problem:

## 1. Use integrals to bound the series

Using graphs and some intuition, we can show that the series is lower bounded by

$$\int_1^\infty{\mathrm{d}x\over x^2+1}={\pi\over4}$$

and upper bounded by

$${1\over2}+\int_1^\infty{\mathrm{d}x\over x^2+1}={2+\pi\over4}$$

Hence, we have that $\displaystyle{\pi\over4}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n^2+1}<{1\over2}+{\pi\over4}$.

## 2. Find the exact value of the series

Alternatively, we can use the Mittag-Leffler expansion of cotangent function:

$$\cot(s)={1\over s}-2s\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over(n\pi)^2-s^2}$$

If we set $s=i\pi$, we obtain

$$\cos(i\pi)={1\over i\pi}-2\pi i\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over(n\pi)^2+\pi^2}$$

According to Euler's formula $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$, we can express cotangent in terms of complex exponentials:

$$\cos\theta={\cos\theta\over\sin\theta}=i{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}\over e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}$$

As a result, the LHS is equal to

$$
\cot(i\pi)=i{e^{-\pi}+e^\pi\over e^{-\pi}-e^\pi}=i{1+e^{2\pi}\over1-e^{2\pi}}
$$

Hence, the equation becomes

$$
i{1+e^{2\pi}\over1-e^{2\pi}}={1\over i\pi}-2\pi i\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over(n\pi)^2+\pi^2}
$$

Multiplying both side by $i\pi$, we obtain

$$
-\pi{1+e^{2\pi}\over1-e^{2\pi}}=1+2\pi^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over(n\pi)^2+\pi^2}
$$
$$
-\pi{1+e^{2\pi}\over1-e^{2\pi}}=1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n^2+1}
$$

Manipulating this further leads us to obtain the exact value of this series:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n^2+1}={\pi\over e^{2\pi}-1}+{\pi-1\over2}
$$